# C# List Logic Fail

Tags: c#

i got an output from a list into an excel file. To simplefile things it could look like this:

4
1
2
3

Now all i wanna do is, put it in the right order:

1
2
3
4

which i did with this code ( isSort contains 4 1 2 3 ):

```
        ...
        var isSortFin = new List<Item>();
        var FirstElement = isSort.First();
        foreach (var Itemd in toSort)
        {
            if (Itemd.Summary != FirstElement.Summary)
            {
                isSortFin.Add(Itemd);
            }
        }

        isSortFin.Add(FirstElement);
        return isSortFin;
```

now my output is:

3 2 1 4

and not the aspired:

1 2 3 4

where do i go wrong?

Comment: If you want to sort why don't you use the `Sort` method?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Where does this code sort? Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: try linq's order by: `isSortFin.OrderBy(i => i.Summary)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `OrderBy` linq extension and sort element.

```
isSort=  isSort.OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();
```

If `Item` is an object, specify property name in `OrderBy` expression to sort on that property.

```
//ex.. 
isSort=  isSort.OrderBy(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: If that's your answer, this question is a duplicate. Vote to close instead of answering.

Comment: May be you are right, but that shouldn't be the reason for down vote.

Comment: I agreed to your second point, probably I could improve the answer including that point, but not agree with point size of the body is small. Anyways thanks for suggestions.

Comment: damn... why did i put roughly ~5 hours in a code ( which i didnt post here, i basically progammed my own sort method xD ) that can be done with a one liner...